# echoing field from database isn't working as expected?

Tags: php, mysql

It's a very simple thing to do but for some reason that im not seeing i cant echo a field from  a mysql database field?

Below is my code which works except for where i need it to echo out the newly updated vote count, any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php
require 'core/init.php';
$_SESSION['score'] = $_POST['score'];
$_SESSION['pid'] = $_POST['pid'];

$score  = $_SESSION['score'];
$pid    = $_SESSION['pid'];
$ipaddy = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$udVote = $db->query("INSERT INTO ratings (score, pid, ip) VALUES ('{$score}','{$pid}','{$ipaddy}')") && $db->query("UPDATE votes SET votecount = votecount +1 WHERE pid='$pid'");

if ($udVote){
    $voteC = $db->query("SELECT votecount FROM votes WHERE pid='$pid' LIMIT 1");
        echo $voteC;
} else {
    echo "error updating database";
}
?>
```

Comment: $voteC might be array , try var_dump($voteC); to check what is it

Comment: Do you get any error messages at all?

Comment: im getting NULL through var_dump and im not getting any error messages?

Comment: `$voteC` isn't your results. It's a results resource. Pass it to something like `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: thanks vch i'll sort that now much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has issues and looks on here for a solution to their issue i'll post the updated and working code below.

```
<?php
require 'core/init.php';

$_SESSION['score'] = $_POST['score'];
$_SESSION['pid'] = $_POST['pid'];

$score  = $_SESSION['score'];
$pid    = $_SESSION['pid'];
$ipaddy = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$records =array();

if($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM votes")){
    if($results->num_rows){
        while($row = $results->fetch_object()){
            $records[] = $row;
        }
        $results->free();
    }
}

$udVote = $db->query("INSERT INTO ratings (score, pid, ip) VALUES ('{$score}','{$pid}','{$ipaddy}')") && $db->query("UPDATE votes SET votecount = votecount +1 WHERE pid='$pid'");

if ($udVote){
    if(!count($records)){
        echo 'no records';
    }else{
        foreach ($records as $r){
            echo escape($r->votecount);
        }
        die();
    }
    }else{
        echo "error updating database";
}


?>
```